# 3D environment for RL research in Academia

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, research, deepmind, open-ai

I'm doing my thesis on `Reinforcement Learning`. My focus on Partially Observable Environments like 3D Games. I want to choose a 3D platform for testing and doing research.

I know some of them. `DeepMind Lab` and `OpenAi Universe`. But my question is that which of these environments is good for me? Is there any environment for this purpose that is benchmark and reliable?

I want a platform that accepted in Academia and reliable. For example DeepMind is not a standard or Open Source friendly, Is it rational to use their platform for research in academia?

What i have to do?

Answer (score 2):

> For example DeepMind [Lab] is not a standard or Open Source friendly

I'm not sure where you got that info from... as far as I'm aware, DeepMind Lab is definitely used in various publications (maybe primarily publications from DeepMind, but still). Considering the [github repo has the GNU GPL 2 license](https://github.com/deepmind/lab/blob/master/LICENSE), it also seems Open Source-friendly to me.

Another framework of which I'm sure that it would widely be considered suitable within academia would be the [Unity ML-Agents Toolkit](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents), which uses the Unity game engine.

I suppose you could also consider using [ViZDoom](http://vizdoom.cs.put.edu.pl/), which is also used in various publications, but (as far as I'm aware) it only supports one specific game (Doom).

I do not have enough experience with using any of the above personally to be able to recommend one of them over the others... but they would all seem suitable to me.